# Bash string replacement/matching: Skip first match

Tags: bash, sed

I have a string that gets piped in to this bash command: `sed -n '/^[*] / { s/^[*] \(.*\)/\1/; s,/,:,; s/-/ /g; p; }'`. The string will always be in this format: `XYZ-1234/a-string-of-words-separated-by-dashes`. However, this solution removes the first dash that is matched and does not add a space after the colon. How can I adjust this so that the output is: `XYZ-1234: A string of words separated by dashes`. Also notice the first character after the colon is capitalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `awk` like this:

```
awk -F'/' '/^[*] /{m=$1;n=$2;gsub(/^[*] /, "", m); gsub(/-/, " ", n); print m": "toupper(substr(n,1,1)) substr(n, 2)}' file > newfile
```

**Details**

- `-F'/'` - the field separator is set to `/`
- `/^[*] /` - finds all lines that start with `*` and space
- `m=$1;n=$2;` - Field 1 is assigned to `m` and Field 2 value is assigned to `n`
- `gsub(/^[*] /, "", m);` - removes the starting `"* "`
- `gsub(/-/, " ", n);` - replaces all `-` with space in `n`
- `print m": "toupper(substr(n,1,1)) substr(n, 2)}'` - prints the result: concatenates `m` value, `:` and space, and then `n` value with the first letter in upper case.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/5DDott):

```
s="* XYZ-1234/a-string-of-words-separated-by-dashes"
awk -F'/' '/^[*] /{m=$1;n=$2;gsub(/^[*] /, "", m); gsub(/-/, " ", n); print m": "toupper(substr(n,1,1)) substr(n, 2)}' <<< "$s"
# => XYZ-1234: A string of words separated by dashes
```